# How to zoom in Xcode 11 Mini-map?

Tags: xcode11

In WWDC 2019 Session 401 "What's new in Xcode", at about 6:30, the presenter shows the minimap and manages to "zoom in" it.

I couldn't find how to do this.

So how to zoom in/out of the minimap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presenter uses <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> (and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>) to enlarge the text in the editor, which also makes the minimap bigger. As far as I know, there's no way (yet) to resize the minimap itself.

Comment: This answer is correct, however, this is not quite what I'd expected. I was looking for resizing the minimap only. But I agree that with the current version of XCode, it doesn't seem possible, so I'll accept the answer anyway.